# Breakpoints for python debugging with roslaunch?

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Coming from a matlab background, Im very found of using breakpoints for debugging...

I know this can be done for python, but it doesn't seem to work when launching my node with roslaunch.
If I use rosrun (or roslaunch with screen output) my node is flooded with sensor data, which overwrites anything I would write as part of my breakpoint debugging.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221594/breakpoints-for-python-debugging-with-roslaunch?/) by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-11-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chenhengwei1999](https://answers.ros.org/users/156328/chenhengwei1999/) on 2023-06-29**:
Hi. I have the same question. Did you find the solution about how to debug rospy code? I will appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to use a launch-prefix to get your python process into pdb

http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chenhengwei1999](https://answers.ros.org/users/156328/chenhengwei1999/) on 2023-06-29**:
Hi, I read your link which is helpful to debug ros's code. But the documentation you supplied is about roscpp, is there any debugging tools that is for rospy?